# Embedded youtube video is breaking my fixed left column nav menu

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position

I have a two column lay out I have a main div that contains a left and right div.

1. The right div is float: right
2. The left div is position: fixed

Each of these divs have have another main div inside of them that i use to position content. In my right div I have another div just for styling my content in side of one of these div's i have this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/72t6iauvX1E?wmode=transparent?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In Chrome the left div does not ever stay fixed. Safari it stays fixed until i play the embedded video. Works fine in Firefox

I have used the ?wmode=transparent to try and fix this, with no luck.

Here is a mock-up of my layout it has the youtube video embedded already and as you can see the left pink div is not fixed remove the embedded iframe and you will see that the div is now fixed as the other content scrolls.

http://jsfiddle.net/2TUaP/

This is driving me crazy. Again i have already tried to add the ?wmode=transparent and ?wmode=opaque to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem with column divs and YouTube embeds.  Most, not all, but most of the videos (code pulled from MySql DB using PHP) play back audio only in a black box.  Occasionally, that box pops out of the column and stacks below the div. Same exact problem in Safari, works fine in Firefox.  Webkit issue?

http://www.centerproductionsinc.com    pick any artist profile

I had to stack the embed outside the column div as a workaround until I can find a real solution.